# This page has moved: HTML redirect vs Frame

Tags: html, redirect, html-frames

I have a personal web site hosted on a server owned by the university where I work. The server allows plain HTML/CSS but no fancy server-side script stuff.

Now I want to move my site to Google Sites, which will be easier for me to keep updated. I would like to know what the best solution for redirecting traffic at the old URL (www.generic.edu/~username/index.html) to the new site is. Two solutions that come to mind are:

- making a plain HTML page with some text saying "click this link to go to the new site".
- a HTML page that loads the new web site into a frame at the old URL.

Is either method clearly superior for some reason, or is there a better third approach?

Comment: Use a meta refresh tag.

Comment: your server doesn't allow you to have a **.htaccess** file ?

Comment: check this : http://www.rapidtables.com/web/dev/html-redirect.htm